# I have an error on django athentication system with authenticate () method

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have an issue with autenticate () method , please help me.
it return to me '' the view didn't return an httpresponse . It returned none instead.

```
def registrazione (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormSito(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data ["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data ["password"]
            User.objects.create_user (
                username = 'username',
                password = 'password'
            )
            
            user = authenticate (request,User)
        else: 
            form = FormSito()
            context = { form : 'form' }
            return render (request,"registration/form/registrazione.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly says what is happening here. You simply don't return anything when the form.is_valid() is true.

```
def registrazione (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormSito(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data ["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data ["password"]
            User.objects.create_user (
                username = 'username',
                password = 'password'
            )
            
            user = authenticate (request,User)
        else: 
            form = FormSito()
            context = { form : 'form' }
        # you had problem here
        return render (request,"registration/form/registrazione.html", context)
```